How to fixed the little bug of sharp conjunction of tikzpictures?
When I use tikz to plot the figure, the conjunction of two lines is not connected so good.
Shown as below, is there any solution to fix it?

Here below is the MWE:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\makeatletter
\def\extractcoord#1#2#3{
  \path let \p1=(#3) in \pgfextra{
    \pgfmathsetmacro#1{\x{1}/\pgf@xx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro#2{\y{1}/\pgf@yy}
    \xdef#1{#1} \xdef#2{#2}
  };
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\sep{0.8}
    \pgfmathsetmacro \a{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro \b{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro \c{sqrt(3)}
    \coordinate (C) at (\a,0);
    \coordinate (D) at (\a,\b*\c/\a);
    \draw (\c*\c/\a,\b*\c/\a) node[above=-2pt] {\tiny$A$} coordinate (A);
    \draw (0,0) node[below=-2pt] {\tiny$B$} coordinate (B);
    \draw (\a,0) node[below=-2pt] {\tiny$C$} coordinate (C);
    \draw (\a,\b*\c/\a) node[above=-2pt] {\tiny$D$} coordinate (D);
    \draw(A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A) -- (D) -- (C);
    \extractcoord{\xA}{\yA}{A}
    \extractcoord{\xB}{\yB}{B}
    \extractcoord{\xC}{\yC}{C}
    \extractcoord{\xD}{\yD}{D}
    \pgfmathsetmacro \Ox{(\a*\xA+\b*\xB+\c*\xC)/(\a+\b+\c)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro \Oy{(\a*\yA+\b*\yB+\c*\yC)/(\a+\b+\c)}
    \coordinate (O) at (\Ox,\Oy);
    \coordinate (a1) at ($(A)!0.5!(O)$);
    \coordinate (b1) at ($(B)!0.5!(O)$);
    \coordinate (c1) at ($(C)!0.5!(O)$);
    \filldraw[fill=gray!50,draw=black,opacity=0.5] (a1) -- (b1) -- (c1) -- cycle;
    \pgfmathsetmacro \d{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro \c{.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro \a{.5*sqrt(3)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro \Ox{(\a*\xA+\c*\xC+\d*\xD)/(\a+\c+\d)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro \Oy{(\a*\yA+\d*\yC+\d*\yD)/(\a+\c+\d)}
    \coordinate (O) at (\Ox,\Oy);
    \coordinate (a2) at ($(A)!0.5!(O)$);
    \coordinate (c2) at ($(C)!0.5!(O)$);
    \coordinate (d2) at ($(D)!0.5!(O)$);
    \filldraw[fill=gray!50,draw=black,opacity=0.5] (a2) -- (c2) -- (d2) -- cycle;
    \node[below] at (.3*\a+\sep,-.25) {\tiny{图1}};
    \draw (B)++(\a+2*\sep,0) node[below=-2pt] {\tiny$B$} coordinate (B);
    \draw (A)++(\a+2*\sep,0) node[above right=-2pt and -3pt] {\tiny$A$} coordinate (A);
    \draw (D)++(\a+2*\sep,0) node[above=-2pt] {\tiny$D$} coordinate (D);
    \draw (C)++(\a+2*\sep,0) node[below=-2pt] {\tiny$C$} coordinate (C);
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A) -- (D) -- (C);
    \draw ($(A)!1!150:(D)$) node[above=-2pt] {\tiny$M$} coordinate (M);
    \draw ($(A)!1!270:(C)$) node[above left=-3pt and -5pt] {\tiny$N$} coordinate (N);
    \draw(A) -- (M) -- (N);
    \draw ($(A)!0.65!45:(B)$) coordinate (P) -- (A);
    \draw ($(A)!0.8!75:(D)$) -- (A);
    \path[name path=AP] (P) -- (A);
    \path[name path=BC] (B) -- (C);
    \path[name intersections={of=AP and BC, by = E}];
    \node[below right=-2pt and -4pt] at (E) {\tiny$E$};
    \node[below] at (.3*\a+4*\sep,-.25) {\tiny{图2}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

-----------------line-------------------------
Another similar case of the problem of option line join:
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,ctex,xfp}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x = .5cm,y = 3cm]
    \foreach \y[count = \x] in {
            0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.5
        }{
            \coordinate (n-\x) at (2*\x-2,\y);
            %\node[above = 2pt, scale = .75] at (2*\x,\y) {\fpeval{1000*\y}}; 
        }
    \foreach \x[evaluate=\x as \y using \x+1] in {1,2,...,7} {
            \draw[very thick,line join=round] (n-\x) -- (n-\y);
        }
    \draw[->,very thick] (0,0) -- (16,0);
    \draw[->,very thick] (0,0) -- (0,1.8);
    \node at (2.3,1.75) {\textbf{离家距离/米}};
    \node at (16.5,-.15) {\textbf{时间/分}};
    \foreach \y in {.3,.6,.9,1.2,1.5} {
            \draw[thick,line join=round] (0,\y)node[left, scale = .75]{\fpeval{1000*\y}} --++ (.2,0);
        }
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,7} {
            \draw[thick,line join=round] (2*\x,0)node[below, scale = .75]{\fpeval{2*\x}} --++ (0,.02);
        }
    \draw[dashed] (6,1.2) -- (6,0);
    \draw[dashed] (6,1.2) -- (0,1.2);
    \draw[dashed] (8,0.6) -- (8,0);
    \draw[dashed] (8,0.6) -- (0,0.6);
    \draw[dashed] (12,0.6) -- (12,0);
    \draw[dashed] (14,1.5) -- (14,0);
    \draw[dashed] (14,1.5) -- (0,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

with the line plot as below:


Thanks to yr sincere help!

Set the line join to round or bevel.

oh,it actually did a good job! But I have another tikzpicture plot the line with the command \foreach, I can't have the point \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) but  seperately \draw (A) -- (B) and \draw (B) -- (C) to use the for-loop. How could I use the option line join?

another mwe is at the last of the origin question, thx!

@Explorer The pgf manual is excellent; use it! Right before line join the option line cap is described..

Aha, the option 'line cap' actually did it! I tried to study TIKZ package with some examples, but what I confronted is that I couldn't spend too much time on the docs, and when I have the necessity, I don't know what key-value to consult in the doc. Just like the option line cap, I could never know that before you told me. Maybe I should be more ane more patient and immersed in the docs. Thanks a lot!
